# Injecting packet is not working on Kali Linux 2018.2

Tags: kali-linux

I am having a problem with injecting packets with `aireplay-ng`.

My monitor mode is working properly but the injection is not working.

My wireless chipset is Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac and the driver is `ath10k_pci`.

Comment: Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/424740

Answer (score 5):

The injection mode isn't supported for the `ath10k`

[Known bugs/limitations:](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k)

> packet injection isn't supported yet

Comment: Then how can i work with that any other option you know ?